# Select on rows with latest date in a table with no groups

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I am trying to achieve the following functionality :

`SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE date1 = (SELECT MAX(date1) FROM table1)`,
which will give me the records with the latest date. I want the same result as above but without a `WHERE` clause since I am creating a materialized view using this statement and I want to implement the `REFRESH CONCURRENTLY` functionality. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can create a MVIEW with a WHERE clause.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name of course, but to REFRESH CONCURRENTLY a materialized view there must not be a WHERE clause in the definition of the materialized view

Comment: I got the same result using the following statement 
`select * from table1 a join table1 b
on a.id = b.id and a.date1=(select max(date1) from table1)`
but is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: The docs only day that the unique index can't have a where clause.  Not that the view itself can't.

Comment: @jjanes My unique index is not on date1 and still keeping the where clause in the sql gives me an error, removing it does not, so I am assuming the where clause shouldnt be a part of the sql

Comment: For me, it behaves according to the docs.  What is your version?  What is the CREATE statement for table, mv, and index?  What is the complete error message?